# Nexus 10 "shareable" part of Android 4.2?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

One of the features of the new Nexus 10 is that it will be ["shareable"](http://www.google.com/nexus/10/#shareable) which, from what I can tell, means that Android will be a multi-user OS. Exactly how Android will handle multiple users I don't know, but I've been craving this feature for a long time.

Any ideas whether this feature will be part of the core of Android 4.2, or if it's just for Nexus 10? I wish I got this on my Nexus 7.

Comment: My understanding is that these are features of **4.2**, whose underpinnings were introduced in 4.0, which are now 'ready' for release.  See: http://www.android.com/whatsnew/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any ideas whether this feature will be part of the core of Android
>   4.2, or if it's just for Nexus 10?

Multi-user support in Android 4.2 will be for ALL TABLETS. So yes, all tabs with Android 4.2 Jelly Bean will have multi-user support.

Google is officially supporting this only for tablets as of now. However, I'm very sure that custom ROM makers will port it for phones. In fact, there are already a bunch of custom ROMs which do this.

> I wish I got this on my Nexus 7.

Nexus 7 is a tablet, so when you upgrade to 4.2, you should get multi-user support.